# Convert int to scrambled Guid and back

Tags: c#, guid

I'm looking for a way to convert an int to a Guid, but not have the next one be sequential to the next. For instance, I have this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var a = Int2Guid(1);
   var b = Int2Guid(2);
}

public static Guid Int2Guid(int value)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
    BitConverter.GetBytes(value).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
    return new Guid(bytes);
}

public static int Guid2Int(Guid value)
{
    byte[] b = value.ToByteArray();
    int bint = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
    return bint;
}
```

This works, but I don't want the numbers to be, nor appear, sequential. From the above example, I get `a = {00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`, but `b = {00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`. I would like something like `{48204b95-9cbb-4295-a6b1-cf05ebda9d0d}`.

Any advice?

Comment: For you set the value is 1 or 2

Comment: So you want to "encrypt" the number so it's represented by a GUID and be able to "decrypt" it?

Comment: @lindexi, apologies, but I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: @phuzi. Correct, I realize I can use some cryptography to encode/decode it, but I was hoping for something a bit simpler

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Feels like there's an underlying reason you've chosen to go down this path.

Comment: @WynDiesel For an int is 4 bytes and the Guid need 16 bytes that you should input 4 ints to make the Guid.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: Generate actual GUIDs and store them next to your ints. Whenever people try to do anything clever with GUIDs, they tend to mess it up and destroy the properties that make GUIDs attractive in the first place (i.e. the "globally unique" part). I doubt this use case is any different.

Comment: @phuzi, I supply this output as a reference for customers. According to management, they make mistakes when coming back, and give the wrong batchnumber. They want to use a GUID for this, similar to Jeron Mosters suggestion. Ideally, I don't want to store another field, when I already have an identifier to work with.

Comment: "they make mistakes when coming back" the chance of making a mistake when quoting a GUID is even greater.

Comment: @phuzi. Completely agree with you. I feel that if the user makes a mistake, it's his problem. However ... this choice is out of my hands. If I had my way, I would just have supplied the int. Simple and clean.

Comment: "Generate a value that customers are not likely to get wrong" is a completely different problem. GUIDs are a very poor choice for that, due to their verbosity. Look into adding something simple like a checksum digit and separating longer numbers by dashes or spaces that your system filters out. You can combine this with solutions that make the number hard to predict or get wrong sequentially, like mixing in the customer's own ID or some value from a predictable, seeded linear PRNG. If you are going to use a GUID as a mandate, go the extra mile and generate and store it properly.

Comment: @phuzi: I assume the idea is that typoing an id that is generated in a consecutive increasing fashion will likely hit another valid id whereas typoing a GUID while probably it will happen more often it is less likely to hit another valid GUID since they are much more spread out... There are definitely better ways to deal with customers mistyping things than this though. :)

Comment: Address the actual problem. Example: Make the user verify another piece of data before proceeding after entering the ID, like a name or address or something else specific to the record. I would take this back to management with some alternative solutions (that you think of before hand) that address the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice solution using AES ECB mode to encrypt guids, works for 16 bytes (what you provided in your example:

```
 public class EncryptGUI
    {
        private Aes aes;

        public EncryptGUI (byte[] key)
        {
            aes = Aes.Create ();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            aes.Key = key;
        }

        public String encryptUID (byte[] guid)
        {
            ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor ();
            byte[] result = aesDecryptor.TransformFinalBlock (guid, 0, guid.Length);
            return ToHex (result);
        }

        public static string ToHex (byte[] data)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder (data.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in data)
                hex.AppendFormat ("{0:x2}", b);
            return hex.ToString ();
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            byte[] key = new byte[16];
            EncryptGUI main = new EncryptGUI (key);

            byte[] guid = new byte[16];
            Console.Out.WriteLine (main.encryptUID (guid));
        }
    }
```

**Note that ECB does not use an IV, which means that you can distinguish different GUID's from each other (as each GUID will be mapped to exactly one ciphertext). But the ciphertext should otherwise simply be identical to the security of the used block cipher and key.**

Answer (score 2):

For Guid need 4 ints or 16 bytes that you should input 4 ints or 16 bytes.

I make the `Int2Guid` input 4 ints.

```
    public static Guid Int2Guid(int value, int value1, int value2, int value3)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
        BitConverter.GetBytes(value).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(value1).CopyTo(bytes, 4);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(value2).CopyTo(bytes, 8);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(value3).CopyTo(bytes, 12);
        return new Guid(bytes);
    }
```

And I make the `Guid2Int` output the int array.

```
    public static int[] Guid2Int(Guid value)
    {
        byte[] b = value.ToByteArray();
        int bint = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
        var bint1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 4);
        var bint2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 8);
        var bint3 = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 12);
        return new[] {bint, bint1, bint2, bint3};
    }
```

When I make a Guid to `Int2Guid` and set it to `Guid2Int` then it can back to the origin.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var foo = Guid2Int(guid);

        var a = Int2Guid(foo[0], foo[1], foo[2], foo[3]);

        Console.WriteLine(a == guid); //true
    }
```

I don't know whether you need it.

Comment: First the OP only has a single int. Second this doesn't seem to satisfy the requirement "but not have the next one be sequential to the next". In your case you have 1, 1, 1, 1 = `00000001-0001-0000-0100-000001000000` and 1, 1, 1, 2 = `00000001-0001-0000-0100-000002000000`. This is exactly the sort of sequential numbers the OP is asking to avoid.

Comment: Could you see @BarrJ answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by hashing the integer using MD5, and using the hash as the source of the Guid:

```
int max = 10;
for (int i = 1; i < max + 1; i++)
{
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    Byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    Byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(intBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(new Guid(hash));
}
```

Note that this is not a cryptographically secure approach.

Comment: This will not produce a valid GUID, as you fill the version and variant bits with "random" values. "Fortunately" there's almost nothing checking these bits anyway. Unfortunately, collisions with this method are, of course, exceptionally easy to produce (never mind cryptographic security), even by another system that uses the same method for completely unrelated things that happen to be numbered. (Or for that matter the same system on different entities.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert GUIDs on msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) don't seem to have a concept of version or variant (at least they are not exposed as fields or properties). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier describes what they call UUIDs and they note are sometimes called GUIDs - Is there somewhere stating that MS GUIDs should be treated as these UUIDs? Just wondering if it is actually wrong to do this "random" approach or is it just that they can't be classed as UUIDs if you do?

Comment: I should add that I never use GUIDs myself so I genuinely have no idea if the MS ones are meant to be the UUIDs described in that wikipedia article. They don't claim to be so I'm not sure we should be judging them as such rather than just as a way of representing a bunch of byte data...

Comment: @Chris it's in the title "Convert int to scrambled Guid and back"

Comment: @Chris: GUID and UUID are different names for the same thing. The `Guid` structure doesn't expose these bits as individual fields, but that doesn't mean they're not there -- `Guid.NewGuid()` will delegate to `UuidCreate` on Windows, which generally produces version 4 GUIDs (i.e. "random" ones). If you produce 128 truly random bits, then you'll have no problem with collisions even though your random bits have no properly set version or variant, but this method does not produce random bits.

Comment: @phuzi: Sorry! I got confused by it not being in the body of the question at all!

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thanks for the info. I feel a little bit smarter now. Or at least better informed. ;-)